# Delete initialized hashicorp's vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I am trying to learn hashicorp's vault and is pretty much unaware with dev vs prod server mode and I accidentally initialized a prod server mode with

`vault operator init` and discarded the unseal keys and root token.

I installed the vault with minikube through helm charts. I tried deleting the helm chart and even the helm repo then proceeds to reinstalling. Despite doing so, the vault is still initialized. I attempted deleting `opt/vault/data` as what another stack overflow post suggests but it has no content anyways thus I'm back with the initial problem.

How do i reinitialize the vault?

Comment: What storage backend did you use during initiliziation?

Comment: I didn't add anything, it was a plain vault operator init

Comment: When Vault started, you had the `-config` parameter on the command line (or else you would use `-dev` which does not store anything). The answer to your question depends on what you put under [`storage` in your configuration file](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage#storage-stanza).

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you have a leftover PVC from the old installation. Just delete it and reinstall again.